# Question About After Effects Paint Tool

Tags: after-effects, video-editor, adobe

I was wondering if anyone has any idea why when I duplicate a layer which has paint on it, it causes the paint to warp in the duplicated layer. I have attached 2 photos which shows what happens. Copy and pasting the effect does not help either.

If anyone knows a solution I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Vika
[image: before]
[image: after]